# The question is regarding 成语－挟怨报复

Tags: idioms

I have a question:

成语－挟怨报复－可以用在下面情形吗？

> 有一位前辈的报告写错了。
>   我善意指正他。
>   后来，我的报告他故意找问题。

下面这些可以吗？
一朝权在手 便把令来行
心胸狭窄 倚势挟权
倚老卖老
窃弄威权

哪一个最好？

Comment: Before you accuse someone of being unfair to you, I hope you can make  sure that it isn't an coincidence. I mean, you pointed out mistakes in his report, may have nothing to do with he later criticized yours - If his critical opinion on your report was justified ( for example, you too, made some mistakes)

Comment: Take easy, @TangHo! It's just an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“挾怨報復”：心懷怨恨而報仇（bear resentment against somebody and retaliate）。
這的確是很常用的詞語，但大部分詞典只有相同意思的“挾嫌報復”。
This is indeed a very common word. But most of the dictionaries list only "挾嫌報復" which has the same meaning.

如果前輩很喜歡“雞蛋裡挑骨頭”或刻意曲解你的報告，是可以用此詞。
If the predecessor is very picky or deliberately twists your reports, you do be able to use this term.

“一朝權在手，便把令來行”：一旦握有權勢，便下命令。(Once the ascendancy is held, the commands are given.)
這和你敘述的情形只有一點相關，就是：他因為是前輩，所以比較有權勢。
但這句不含“故意找麻煩（報仇）”的意思。
“便把令來行”不一定和報仇有關。
There is only one point related to the situation; i.e., because of being a senior, he is more powerful.
But this sentence doesn't mean "deliberately looking for trouble (revenge)".
"便把令來行" is not necessarily related to revenge.

“心胸狹窄，倚勢挾權”：此二詞連在一起是指“度量小的人濫用權勢”。
這和你敘述的情形有兩點相關：
其一，你指正他，但他不能包容，是和“心胸狹窄”有關。
其二，他用前輩的權勢。
這句有一點“報仇”的意思，但不太明顯。
"心胸狹窄，倚勢挾權": These two phrases together mean that "a narrow-minded person abuses the privilege".
There are two aspects related to the case.
1. You corrected his reports, but he couldn't tolerate. It's connected with "心胸狹窄".
2. He takes advantage of the power of a predecessor.
This sentence implies "revenge" a little, but less obvious.

“倚老賣老”：賣弄老資格 (to flaunt one's seniority)。
這和你敘述的情形只有一點相關，就是：他是前輩。
This is relevant only to that "he is a predecessor".

“竊弄威權”：暗地裡玩弄權勢 (to abuse authority secretly)。
這和你敘述的情形只有一點相關，就是：他用前輩的權勢。
This is related to that "he uses the power of a predecessor".

比較這幾個詞語，還是“挾怨報復／挾嫌報復”較適用。
Comparison of these words, "挾怨報復／挾嫌報復" is still more applicable.
Good choice!

Answer (score 0):

**依你描述**，你的这位前辈表现出来的是「刚愎自用」，「心胸狭窄」，「不容异已」的性情。

而他的动机可以用「记仇」来形容。

至于行为本身则可说是「恶意刁难」。

- 「刚愎自用」：总以为自己一定对，一意孤行地抗拒一切不同的意见。
- 「心胸狭窄」: 没有原谅他人的修养
- 「不容异已」: 固执地排除一切反对者
- 「记仇」: 把仇恨不满都常记心中
- 「恶意刁难」: 恶意地找人麻烦

**According to your description**, your senior fellow employee showed he has a temperament of 「刚愎自用」(self-willed), 「心胸狭窄」(narrow-minded) and  「不容异已」(intolerance to opinion different from his own).

And his motives can be described as 「记仇」(vengeful).

As for the act itself, it can be said to be 「恶意刁难」(maliciously seeking trouble for others)

- 「刚愎自用」(self-willed) : always thought he must be right, bent on resisting all the different views.
- 「心胸狭窄」(narrow-minded): never forgive
- 「不容异已」(intolerance of views different from his own): stubbornly ruled out all opponents
- 「记仇」(Vengeful): always hold grudge
- 「恶意刁难」(maliciously seek trouble for others)

> I have never heard of 挟怨报复 as an idiom,
>
> 挟怨 can be translated to "hold a grudge"
>
> 报复 means "revenge"
>
> 挟怨报复 means "hold a grudge and seek revenge"